# Call python's object method from flask jinja2 html file

Tags: python, flask, pytube

I am trying to create youtube video downloader application using pytube and flask. All is done, except that a want to call pytube's stream download method from within the html script tag. How can i do it.

Here's my flask code

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from pytube import YouTube
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html", data=None)
        
    @app.route("/download", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def downloadVideo():
        if request.method == "POST":
            url = request.form["videourl"]
            if url:
                yt = YouTube(url)
                title = yt.title
                thumbnail = yt.thumbnail_url
                streams = yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
                data = [title, thumbnail, streams, yt]
                
                return render_template("index.html", data=data)
        
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

and here's my html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Youtube Downloader </title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="header">
                        <div>
                            <img src="static/img/icon.png" width="48" height="48">
                            <h2> Youtube Downloader </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p> Convert and download youtube videos </p>
                            <p> in MP4 for free </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                {% if not data %}
                    <div class="dform">
                        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/download", method="POST">
                            <div class="inputfield">
                                <input type="input" name="videourl" placeholder="Search or Paste youtube link here" autocomplete="off">
                                <button type="submit"> Download </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <div class="videoinfo">
                        <img src="" class="thumbnail">
                        <h2> {{data[0]}} </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quality">
                        <select id="streams">
                            {% for stream in data[2][:3] %} 
                                <option value="{{stream.itag}}"> {{stream.resolution}} </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    const image = document.querySelector(".thumbnail");
                    const select = document.querySelector("select");
    
                    let url = `{{data[1]}}`;
                        if (image) {
                            image.src = `${url}`;
    
                            window.addEventListener('change', function() {
                                var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
                                console.log(option);
                                {% set stream = data[3].get_by_itag(option) %}
                                {% stream.download() %}
                        });
                    }
                </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to download the video using itag when a user clicks an option in the select element by using pytube get_by_itag() method.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're attempting? When you say "I'm trying to download the video" do you mean start a file download on the user's computer for a particular youtube tag when they click on a link?

Comment: @barryodev pytube stream objects let us download videos in a specific resolution by an itag, which is unique for each resolution. I know the itag and want to call pytube.streams.get_by_itag(itag) function from within the javascript. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to do two things. You want to create a route on your flask app that will let serve up the youtube video based on an itag, and you want to be able to call that route from javascript.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68160207/15786191) shows how to create a route to download the video.

To call a url that starts a file download from javascript you'll need to use the fetch method and open that link into an iFrame. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery) covers it.

Let me know if that covers your question.